# Mixing HTML ids causing multidimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to group a set of INPUT-elements in a Javascript array and got confused on why I got a multi-dimensional array back (array named 'urls' in the code below).
It turned out I had mixed up the fourth element with the same id as the first element.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script language="javascript">
    function validate() {
        var form = document.forms.conf;

        var urls = new Array(form.url1, form.url2, form.url3, form.url4);
        alert(urls[0].value);  // returns 'undefined'
        alert(urls[0][0].value);  // works
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="conf">
    <input type="text" name="url1" id="url1">
    <input type="text" name="url2" id="url2">
    <input type="text" name="url3" id="url3">
    <input type="text" name="url4" id="url1"><br />
    <button type="button" onclick="javascript:validate();">Push me</button>
</form>

</body>
</html
```

My question is, why does this happen? What relationship does the HTML attribute 'id' have to 'document.forms.form_name.element'? And why does it cause it to put it in a multi-dimensional array?
The behavior seems to be the same cross-browser too, so it have to be some definition I'm not aware of.

Comment: Please note that IDs should be unique! If you want an array, do it with same names rather than IDs. Also not that the pseudo label *javascript:* is unnecessary anywhere except IE browsers which have a VBScript as the first script on the page

Comment: Also note that since you are using document.forms access, I would expect form.url1 to be equivalent to form.elements["url1"] and hence use the name of the element. In your case you seem to manage to confuse the issue by having same IDs which is illegal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form will have a property for each form control that has a name or id. The name of that property will be the same as the name or id. If multiple elements share a name (or, illegally, an id) then the property will contain an NodeList instead of a single HTMLElementNode.

The first input has the name (and id) `url1`.
The last input has the id `url1`

So `form.url1` becomes a NodeList consisting of those two elements.